# Form action attribute not working on jQuery submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-panelbar

I have an ASP.NET MVC application using Kendo UI v2015.2.624, bootstrap 3.4.1 and jquery 2.2.4. In one of the views I have built a kind of accordion using an unordered list ul with some li items in it and using a kendoPanelBar. These li items can be expanded and collapsed.

**View (cshmtl)**:

```
@model MyDTOs.customDTO

<form id="myForm" method="post">    
    <div id="divExample">
        <ul id="panelBarExample" class="panelBarExample">
            <li class="k-state-active">                
                <span>General Data</span>
                <div class="rootRow">                    
                    @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Path/To/Views/_View1.cshtml", Model);}

                    <input type="hidden" name="myId" value="@Model.Id" />
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="k-state-active">

                <span>Activities Data</span>
                <div class="rootRow">

                    <section id="Activities">
                        @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/Path/To/Views/WizardStep1/_Activities.cshtml", Model.DataWizard); }

                    </section>
                </div>
            </li>

            <!-- and more li items -->
       </ul>
    </div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#panelBarExample").kendoPanelBar({
          expandMode: "multiple",
          activate: function(e){
              // #scheduler is a kendoScheduler
              if(e.sender.select().find('#scheduler').length > 0)
                  if($('#scheduler').getKendoScheduler() != null)
                      $('#scheduler').getKendoScheduler().refresh();
          }
      });
    });

       // More functions here

       function saveDataAndReturnPreviousView() {
           var form = $("form#myForm");
           form.attr("action", "@Url.Action("SaveDataAndReturnPreviousView","myController")");
           form.submit();
        }

        // More functions here

</script>
}
```

As an example, the UI has the following look:

[image]

**MyController**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveDataAndReturnPreviousView(customDTO myDto)
    {
        //  Do some stuff            

        //  Redirect to the correct view
        return RedirectToAction(<action name here>,<controller name here>, <route values here>);            
    }
```

When a button is clicked on the view, the saveDataAndReturnPreviousView function gets called (see this function on the above piece of javascript code). Then the corresponding action SaveDataAndReturnPreviousView gets called on the controller, and finally I do some stuff there and redirect to show another view.

This is correctly working except when "General Data" panel is expanded before I click on the button.
In conclusion this is what is happening:

1. If "General Data" panel is expanded it does not work, javascript line code where
   form is submitted (form.submit()) is reached and executed but
   SaveDataAndReturnPreviousView action in the controller is never
   executed.
2. If "General Data" panel is collapsed then it works, no problems here. It behaves as expected.

In both cases it does not matter the state of the other panels (expanded or collapsed). The only problem is with first panel, when it is expanded it does not work.

So any ideas what is happening this strange behaviour in case 1?

In Google Chrome DevTools, there are no errors in the console.

**UPDATE 25/02/2021**:

It seems the problem comes from partial view _View1.cshtml. It does not matter if it is the first panel, the second or the third and so on, if this panel contains the partial view _View1 then form submit fails, no error message in shown in Google Chrome DevTools console.

I have exactly detected which line of the partial view is causing the form submit is not working.

Below line is the culprit in _View1.cshtml:

> //Below @Html.WfTextBoxFor is an extension method for
> System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper, //see later in this post
>
> @Html.WfTextBoxFor(x => x.numeroHora, new { @class = "k-textbox",
> @style = "width:100%" })

Note: x.numeroHora is of type decimal? and I have ensured it is not null, its value in this case is 1,5 (symbol ',' is the decimal sign in spanish format)

I have changed x.numeroHora by another field which is not a decimal?, for example a string or int, and it works, then form submit works but when this field is of type decimal? it does not work. It seems the problem is when the field is of type decimal? any other type works successfully. In the view I have other @Html.WfTextBoxFor items which field is not of type decimal? and all them work successfully. When I comment the line of code @Html.WfTextBoxFor(x => x.numeroHora, new { @class = "k-textbox", @style = "width:100%" } then form submit works.

Also, @Html.WfTextBoxFor is an extension method for System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper defined in a static class:

```
namespace My.MVC.Helpers
{
    public static class WfHtmlExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString WfTextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            bool bEditable = htmlHelper.IsWfEditable(expression);
            bool bVisible = htmlHelper.IsWfVisible(expression);

            return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(expression, htmlAttributes, bEditable, bVisible); // This calls method below
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, object htmlAttributes, bool editable, bool bVisible)
        {
            MvcHtmlString html = default(MvcHtmlString);

            RouteValueDictionary routeValues = htmlAttributes == null ? new RouteValueDictionary() : new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
            AddWfAttributesClass(routeValues, !editable, !bVisible);
            html = System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(htmlHelper, expression, routeValues);

            return html;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem when the type is decimal?

**System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper is version 5.2.7.0 (I have installed  Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc and Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.es version 5.2.7.0 nuget packages)**

**UPDATE 01/03/2021**:

I have analyzed the network traffic using Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger and it does not show anything, no traffic, simply web page hangs, no controller method is getting called.

Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger screenshot:

[image]

Comment: If you move General Data down the list, is it still the problem one? Or does the new one at the top now cause the problem? What does the html rendered from _View1.cshtml look like?

Comment: when the form.submit line runs, do you see anything in the Chrome DevTools network tab showing a call to a controller and/or any error code?

Comment: @NigelK I have updated the post. Please, see UPDATE 25/02/2021. I have put the panel in the second place and it also fails. The problem is within the partial view _View1. There is an extension method Html.WfTextBoxFor which is the culprit but I do not know how to solve it. It seems the DTO field in the lambda expression does not work when form submit. This field is of type decimal?. The same extension method with other field types such as string, int are working.

Comment: @G_P I have updated the post. Please, see UPDATE 25/02/2021. Regarding your questions, from Google Chrome DevTools I have put a breakpoint in the javascript line where form submit is executed, and I have ensured this line is reached and executed but then controller action is not executed. I have put a breakpoint in the first line in the controller action and it never stops there. Also no errors are shown in Chrome DevTools console tab. In Network tab there is no call to the controller. Basically, once form submit is executed page freezes, it does nothing, no errors appear.

Comment: It does sound like a problem with the decimal separator being a comma. Something like your culture being spanish in the browser but the server is en-US or something. If the model binder cannot match the type of arguments in the controller action to the data coming in, the action won't run. If you use something like Telerik Fiddler to watch the http traffic, I expect you would see the call being made but failing with a 500 error.

Comment: @NigelK That make sense. And how could I solve this? maybe converting decimal into string in the lambda expression x.numeroHora?

Comment: @NigelK my client browser is in spanish and the web server where app resides is configured correctly with Spain region and comma as decimal sign. It is very rare.

Comment: @NigelK Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger does not show anything. See my updated post 01/03/2021